# Mysql query with variable flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

can someone help me with this? 
i'm a new programmer and for a little project i need to create a profile page for every user in the database in flask

```
@app.route("/idpage/<int:page_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def profilepage(page_id):
    profile=engine.execute("SELECT username,password FROM tutorial WHERE id=" +page_id+ "").fetchall()
    return render_template('viewprofile.html', profile=profile)
```

The error gave me is

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

this is my second "program" can i find some documentation for using sql?

Comment: Since you are just starting: Great choice on Flask, not so great choice on MySQL. Use Postgres. It's a much better database and it has less weird gotchas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never build queries by directly inserting user input into them. This opens you up to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Instead, you should use [bind parameters](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing).

```
engine.execute("SELECT username, password FROM tutorial WHERE id = ?", page_id)
```

Note, the bind symbol varies from driver to driver, but will typically be one of `?` or `%s`.

Comment: AFAIK it's always `%s` or `%(name)s`, and never `%d` (not even for numbers)

Comment: I've only used `s` but I wasn't sure if some drivers accepted others. I updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you're right on the `%s`, that threw me when I was starting with SQLAlchemy. The approach is right, though. +1

Comment: While in principle this answer is much better than mine (I am happy to concede that), I think it is too concise for a coding (not just Python) newbie. I would suggest that you give him the bind line as well to not confuse him unnecessarily.